# Is this a US Civil War uniform?

Tags: military, identification, american-civil-war, uniform

[image: TinTypeImageSoldier]

Image is a photo of an original tin type (photographic method introduced in 1856, in popular production until roughly 1867), hat appears to be U.S. Civil War - Union, "X" patch on right front breast region, single row of buttons, rectangular belt buckle, sword is straight-bladed, heavy "D" guard, does not appear to have the same guard as a NCO sword, though.

Can anyone identify / confirm that this image is Civil War?
Any other details?

Answer (score 11):

Looks like your soldier may be a member of the [56th Regiment
New York Volunteers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/56th_New_York_Volunteer_Infantry), also known as the [10th Legion](https://dmna.ny.gov/historic/reghist/civil/infantry/56thInf/56thInfCWN.htm) (hence the patch).

You can see a couple of soldiers with similar uniforms at a site [here](http://www.loc.gov/pictures/item/2010648873/) and [here](http://www.loc.gov/pictures/item/2010650490/):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great find. I suspected a Tenth Legion connection but couldn't track it down.

Comment: Looks like a match!